# Verify SMTP server authentication via java api (Healthcheck including AUTH)

Tags: java, email, smtp, jakarta-mail

### Goal

I want to implement a health check for an SMTP server. This healthcheck should include authentication so that I know not only know if the server is available but if I will be able to send emails using the given certificate.

I understand that this [is possible using Telnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMTP_Authentication#Details).

If possible I would like something a little more highlevel. At the moment I'm using `javax.mail.Session`, `javax.mail.Transport`, etc.

### Questions

Is it possible to verify if an SMTP server will (likely) accept my request by authenticating using a certificate, without sending something like a testmail to the server using simple java API?

Also another question I have is if i should use a Session for a MimeMessage and then send these using the static Transport#send method. Or should can I use something where I get an instance. Main thing I would like to achieve is to retrieve the returncode from the server also in succesful cases.

I'm also okay with using a different library.

For reference some code of how I'm preparing the session and messages atm.

```
public class SmtpMailService {

    public Session prepareSession() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
        return Session.getInstance(properties, null);
    }

    public List<MimeMessage> sendMessages(List<MimeMessage> messages) {
        Iterator<MimeMessage> m = messages.iterator();

        while (m.hasNext()) {
            MimeMessage currentMessage = m.next();
            try {
                Transport.send(currentMessage);
                m.remove();
            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                break;
            }
        }

        List<MimeMessage> mailsWithError = StreamUtils.asList(m);
        return mailsWithError;
    }
}
```

And how I then send the mails.

```
public class SmtpMailSenderService {
    private SmtpMailService mailerService;

    public List<SmtpEmailNotificationRecipient> sendNotificationMails(final List<SmtpEmailNotificationRecipient> recipients,
            final SmtpMailTemplate templateId, final Map<String, String> templateValues) {

        // templating stuff

        final Session smtpSession = mailerService.prepareSession();
        final List<MimeMessage> messages = mailerService.prepareMessages(smtpSession, recipients, email);

        final List<MimeMessage> unsentMessages = mailerService.sendMessages(messages);

        return collectRemainingRecipients(unsentMessages);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't tell if the server will let you send mail without actually sending mail.  And then the recipient will matter too.

You can get JavaMail to throw an exception on success and the exception will include the return code.  Set the [`mail.smtp.reportsuccess`](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/mail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html#mail.smtp.reportsuccess) Session property to true.  See the [smtpsend.java](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mail/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/smtpsend.java) sample program.

If you already have a Transport object, you might was well use it instead of the static send method.